# Intensity of light at a point

Tags: optics, visible-light, polarization, intensity

Unpolarized light of intensity I scattered from point A. Intensity of light perceive by given observer is :-[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfyMT.png)

Unpolarized light has vibrations in all planes. And at a point A in its path the observer sees it along one of axes of these planes. This is the scattering that's happening at A and nothing else.
The answer key says its $I/2+(I/2)$ $sin^2 Θ$. I do not have a clue how that happens. Am i missing something in my concept here? Please help me

Comment: We don't know what your concept is. How did you arrive at $I\sin(\theta)$? Are you bothered by that function being negative?

Comment: I just used vector components along the angle 90-Θ i.e the angle between the line of sight of observer and propagation. Component of I along 90-Θ gives I cos(90-Θ) = I sinΘ. I haven't applied any other concept of interference. I don't know how a negative function would be possible but any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by scattered? I'm a native spanish speaker and what I understand from scattering is the fact that diferent wavelenght split when passing trought a material. In any case,  I don't get what is happening on point A

Comment: The light is travelling along a straight line through A unpolarized. The observer is looking at a point A which is in the path of the light from a position at an angle to the path. Scattering isn't taking place. And I need to find what intensity of light is seen by the observer.

Comment: If it is traveling along that line, the light wont reach the observer who is outside the path. (Or if you're considering a planar wave perpendicular to that line, he would get the same intensity). I still don't get what is happening to the light.

Comment: You say the light isn't reflected, refracted, scattered, difracted, passing throught a polarizator.. I don't get the problem. How did you even got $I*sin\theta$?

Comment: i added the photo of what I've done

Comment: I see now. Intensity (and waves) doens't work that way. But I don't understand the situation, or what they expected you to have done, so I'm sorry I can't help.

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal Intensity is not a vector quantity, so you can't use vector components here. If you give us more information that what is at A which is scattering the light would help us solve the problem.

Comment: @sslucifer linear polarization isn't a vector quantity either. It's rank-2, so $\exp(2i\theta)$ should be in the answer.

Comment: @sslucifer he said there was no scattering at A.

Comment: A is just a point in the path of the light.  Like imagine a straight line and any point on that line and look at that point from an angle. So its just unpolarized light travelling and A is a point that happens to be in its path. And you are looking at A from an angle. So what is the intensity for the person viewing it? That's the question

Comment: It's quite unclear, what does scattering refers tohere?

Comment: @Sarcasm i updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the light is travelling from the sun, we can see that the plane of unpolarised light is at an angle (90-θ) from the observer with reference to the horizontal line for the given angle. Now since the light is unpolarised, it vibrates in 2 directions, say X-axis and Y-axis in our case. So on passing through a polarizer (in a natural phenomena like this, a polarizer is usually the small particles in nature whose size are comparable to the wavelength of light), the vibrations of light of any one direction is completely absorbed. Also the light travels at an angle of (90-θ) w.r.t observer as said above (since plane of polarization is the horizontal line from the sun). Hence the net intensity will be calculated using Malus Law and the concept of absorption of vibration of light in a particular direction. 
See the solution I am providing for greater clarity
[image]